# VS2010 RC - Is intellisense broken? How do I turn it on?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I installed the RC of VS2010 side-by-side with VS2008 SP1. VS2010 Intellisense appears to be broken, or at least not functioning as expected. I can only get intellisense if I hit CTRL + spacebar. Then after selecting the memebr from the intellisense list, hit the period again, and then CTRL + space again.

If intellisense broken or just turned off? How do I fix it?

Update #1 - I do have Resharper 4.5 installed on VS2008.

UPDATE #2 - I installed the hot fix. No go. Then, I looked at the options under Tools > Options > Text Editor. As it turns out, under Statement Completion, the option to Auto list members was unchecked. Once I checked that option, intellisense was functioning as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Tools > Options > Text Editor > LANGUAGE >  under Statement Completion group, select the option to "Auto list members".

Answer (score 2):

They're patching issues with intellisense.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/15/patch-for-vs-2010-rc-intellisense-crash-issue-now-available.aspx

-- Edit --
As pointed out by the comments below, this is not the same issue.  I was just pointing out that MS is fixing issues with intellisense.  It might not be worth beating yourself up looking for a misconfiguration on your system.

Comment: Yup, his blog points to https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=26662&wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: That wouldn't cause intellisense to turn off.  That's a crash in intellisense on systems that use UIA (screen readers, tablets, multi-touch).

Comment: I'm also having issues with InteliSense. It takes like 3min to show up the members list, instead of showing up instantly, as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have ReSharper installed with Visual Studio 2008?  ReSharper (in VS2008) turns off Intellisense explicitly in order to replace it with their own.

If this is the case, you can turn it back on with the options under `Tools->Options->Text Editor->[language]` (and sometimes also under the `Intellisense` node under each language).

For example, for C#, the first checkbox under `Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Intellisense` is "Show completion list after a character is typed".  Make sure that is checked.