# Visual Studio 2010 RC Intellisense doesn´t work 

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I installed VS2010 on my Windows 7 x64...
The patch to fix Intellisense as well (http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=26662)...

But my C# Intellisense doesn´t work... It doesn´t crash, but nothing happens when I typing... Just if I press a Ctrl+Backspace it appears...

In my Javascript file the Intellisense is working fine...

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT**: These are the options that should be enabled:

`Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->General->Auto list members`
`Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->General->Parameter information`
`Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Intellisense->Show completion list after a character is typed`

---

See my response to [VS2010 RC - Is intellisense broken? How do I turn it on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269437/vs2010-rc-is-intellisense-broken-how-do-i-turn-it-on/2269719#2269719):

> Did you have ReSharper installed with Visual Studio 2008?  ReSharper (in VS2008) turns off Intellisense explicitly in order to replace it with their own.
>
> If this is the case, you can turn it back on with the options under `Tools->Options->Text Editor->[language]` (and sometimes also under the `Intellisense` node under each language).
>
> For example, for C#, the first checkbox under `Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Intellisense` is "Show completion list after a character is typed".  Make sure that is checked.

Comment: Yes, I have ReSharper with VS2008...
But the option "Show completion list after a character is typed" of C# language is already checked...
Anything else?

Thanks

Comment: Try the first two checkboxes under Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#(->General) ("Auto list members" and "Parameter information").  I believe those also have to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Gu posted an entry about [Intellisence crashing](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/11/intellisense-crashing-fix-for-vs-2010.aspx) with VS2010 RC1.  And later about [a patch](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/15/patch-for-vs-2010-rc-intellisense-crash-issue-now-available.aspx).  This may be causing your problem.  If not try [Noah's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311532/visual-studio-2010-rc-intellisense-doesnt-work/2312366#2312366) suggestion.

Comment: Sorry I read over that part.  But I am going to leave this answer because it may provide insight to other people that are having similar issues.